# Fazendo deploy com SVN

Tags: deploy, svn

Eu preciso configurar meu ambiente para fazer o versionamento de código PHP, mas estou com dúvidas de 'por onde começar'. O repositório no servidor Linux/Apache está criado e eu já instalei o Tortoise na minha máquina e ai começaram as dúvidas.

1) Qual diretório utilizar localmente?

Por exemplo, meu diretório atual `/localhost/app` e tenho o código lá então:

a) devo criar o SVN na mesma pasta (pois é lá que vou alterar) e depois fazer o *checkout*, ou

b) devo ter um diretório 'a parte' para o SVN, e depois de tudo ok em *localhost*, copiar para a pasta do SVN via um `xcopy` e então executar o *checkout*?

2) Sincronia remota

Quando subir os arquivos e a versão estiver 'valendo', eu estarei jogando os arquivos em `/srv/svn` no servidor, porém para realmente estar valendo o certo era jogar para `/srv/httpd/app` por exemplo, como eu devo fazer para sobrepor a versão vigente por esta que acabei de subir?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

> Qual diretório utilizar localmente ? Por exemplo, meu diretorio atual /localhost/app e tenho o código lá então: a) devo criar o SVN na mesma pasta (pois é lá que vou alterar) e depois fazer o checkout, ou b) devo ter um diretório 'a parte' para o SVN, e depois de tudo ok em localhost, copiar para a pasta do SVN via um xcopy e então executar o checkout ?

A - Não vejo porque fazer a B em condições normais, mas se tiver alguma razão plausível pode fazer. Não faça nada sem motivo, como não vê motivo, e muitos não verão, faça a A.

> 2) Sincronia remota ? Quando subir os arquivos e a versão estiver 'valendo', eu estarei jogando os arquivos em /srv/svn no servidor, porém para realmente estar valendo o certo era jogar para /srv/httpd/app por exemplo, como eu devo fazer para sobrepor a versão vigente por esta que acabei de subir ?

Não sei se entendi, principalmente o que é "valendo". Você terá uma pasta com o projeto na sua máquina e uma pasta com o projeto no servidor, pronto, não tem mais nada. Tem o SVN rodando nos 2, já foi configurado, só tem que usar comando do SVN para sincronizar entre eles. Esta é a parte do SVN.

Se está falando do *deploy*, ou seja a implantação em produção, geralmente tem um mecanismo que cuida disto quando deve fazer o *deploy*, em muitos casos não é só copiar para o local onde vai rodar, tem algum *script* que cuida disto. Mas se for só copiar, então deixe um `xcopy` na palma da mão para fazer o *deploy*.

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pelas respostas.

Eu ja consegui criar um repositorio local e à ele adicionar uma pasta de código que está valendo e fazer o checkout, ou seja, em meu repositório local está ok, porém para o remoto realmente ainda não consegui conectar.

Só uma dúvida, como você citou o deploy, é possível dentro do processo de checkout onde eu envio o HEAD fazer automaticamente a chamada à um programa ou eu devo fazer isso manualmente (por exemplo um bash para sincronia do deploy para produção) ?

Comment: Sim, é spossível, tem uns *hooks* que podem ser configurados, mas cuidado para não fazer *deploy* tão automático, a não ser que saiba muito o que está fazendo e cuide de todos os detalhes para tratar das falhas e que todas sejam pegam antes de fazer o *deploy*.

Comment: Obrigado @Maniero eu ja estou com o ambiente pronto mas por conta de tempo nao pude priorizar testes (tanto de upload versao local para o servidor como da promocao da versao que sera considerada producao).